# Why does success flash message always pop up on top of login page?

Tags: css, ejs

i have coded to show flash messages when use got successfully registered. But unfortunately flash message always pop up on top of login page. i mentioned my code below...! someone help me [image]
   **login.ejs**

```
<div style=" width:450px; margin: auto; width: 50%; padding: 10px; } ">
<% if( success_msg) { %>
    <p class="isa_success"><i class="fa fa-times-circle"></i><%= success_msg  
%></p>
<%  } else if(error_msg){ %>
  <p class="isa_error"><i class="fa fa-times-circle"></i><%= error_msg  %> 
</p>
<% } else if(error)  { %>
  <p class="isa_error"><i class="fa fa-times-circle"></i><%= error  %></p>
<% }  else { %>
 <p></p>
<% }  %>
 </div>
```

Comment: I don't know much about ejs, but I don't like the look of that trailing } in the style of that top div

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<div style=" width:450px; margin: auto; width: 50%; padding: 10px; } ">
<% if( success_msg.length>0) { %>
    <p class="isa_success"><i class="fa fa-times-circle"></i><%= success_msg  
%></p>
<%  } else if(error_msg){ %>
  <p class="isa_error"><i class="fa fa-times-circle"></i><%= error_msg  %> 
</p>
<% } else if(error)  { %>
  <p class="isa_error"><i class="fa fa-times-circle"></i><%= error  %></p>
<% }  else { %>
 <p></p>
<% }  %>
 </div>
```