# How to convert handlebars to ejs that i mentioned below

Tags: handlebars.js, ejs

can someone tell me how to convert handlebar code to ejs that i mentioned below

```
                {{#if success_msg}}
                 <div class="alert alert-success"> 
                                   {{success_msg}}</div>
                {{/if}}

                {{#if error_msg}}
                 <div class="alert alert-danger"> 
                                     {{error_msg}}</div>
                {{/if}}

                {{#if error}}
                <div class="alert alert-danger"> 
                                    {{error}}</div>
                {{/if}}
```

Comment: Why not just render the handlebars into html with sample variables, and then rev-engineer the html into ejs? (assuming that you're familiar with html and that there is more than just what is posted above?).

Is it the if statements that you're trying to figure out?

Comment: can you plz check my previous post : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54150529/why-does-success-flash-message-always-pop-up-on-top-of-login-page?noredirect=1#comment95132279_54150529

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
                 <%if (success_msg){%>
                 <div class="alert alert-success"> 
                              <%=success_message %></div>
                <%}%>

                <%if (error_msg){%>
                 <div class="alert alert-danger"> 
                              <%=error_msg%></div>
                <%}%>

                <%if (error){%>
                 <div class="alert alert-danger"> 
                              <%=error%></div>
                <%}%>
```

Comment: Could plz check this post : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54150529/why-does-success-flash-message-always-pop-up-on-top-of-login-page?noredirect=1#comment95132279_54150529

Comment: Check it now I have answered it

Comment: success_msg != success_message